# Can I build a large App Service in Azure and then turn it off when I'm not using it?

Tags: azure

We're doing a couple of demos next month and I need a monster machine to make the demo look good.

What I'd like to do is build a really large App Service, but keep it shut down when we weren't doing a demo.  When I stop my App Services, I get a message saying I'm still going to be charged.

Is there any way to stop App Service Plans or App Services when they're not being used and start them up again on the day of the demo?

Comment: You can automate the deployment of your app then just create it the day of the demo ?

Comment: Deploying isn't an issue.  Destroying a machine and then creating it is a pain.  There are many switches to get right and I'm not at the point where I want to learn Azure scripting just to get to the point where I can automatically create the same machine.  After validating the machine, loading it with data and validating that everything is right, I just want to flip a switch.

Comment: Is it an app service or a VM ? these are pretty different

Comment: It's an App Service (was I unclear in the original question).  VMs are a piece of cake to shut down on a schedule.

Comment: App service are not "machine". What kind of configuration are you talking about ? it is pretty straight forward to configure it.

Comment: It is not 'straight forward' to configure either an App Service or a VM.  There are several questions that you need to get right.  May be simple when you have no pressure but I know for a fact that on demo day, every place where you have to make a decision is an opening for disaster.  I just want one switch to flip after I've validated a service.

Answer (score 0):

We have no way to stop app service plan and just ca stop app service. But your app service plan is not free tier, you will continue to charge it.So now you have to two choice.

1. You use free app service plan, but it has [some easy features](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/). It use shared instance
2. You make your solution temporary is to create a deployment script, using Powershell or [Resource manager Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) then you can deploy your solution for exactly as long as you need it and then delete it again when you don't.